# where to find The methods of HttpHeaders class in spring framework

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-mvc

I came across some code which is difficult to understand since I am unaware of the methods it use to achieve.

The class is `HttpHeaders` of spring framework. It had some methods like,

```
setAuthorization()
setUserAgent()
setAccept()
```

What does these methods do? Any help is appreciated. The question appears to be less researched but I tried [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html) but to no use. I just want to know what does these methods do in the background and to know the working of these methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your api links are wrong.

In fact, you should look into [Spring for Andriod](http://docs.spring.io/spring-android/docs/current/api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html) api, there, you can find those methods'  description.

```
setAuthorization()
setUserAgent()
setAccept()
```

Comment: So far, I don't have enough reputation to upvote.. :)

Comment: @Anshu I know you don't have enough reputation to upvote, but can accept it by right-mark sign :)